# How to properly delete recursively defined objects in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, class, object, handle, recursive-datastructures

I defined an object handle class in MATLAB which looks like following:

```
classdef object < handle

    properties
        size
        neighbour
    end
    
    methods
        function g = object(size)
            g.size = size;
            g.neighbour = object.empty(0,0);
        end
        
        function link_g2g(g,neighbour)
            g.neighbour(end+1)=neighbour;
            neighbour.neighbour(end+1)=g;
        end
        
    end
end
```

As you can see it is possible that those objects are linked together by the property `neighbour`.

I now need to delete those links in a efficient way.
First I thought that the links are just pointers to one of the objects and if I would delete `object(x)`, which is for example linked to `object(y)`:

`object(x).neighbour(z)==object(y)` and
`object(y).neighbour(p)==object(x)`

then I also would delete `object(x)` as a neighbour of `object(y)`. But this seems not to be the case since it is not a pointer but some kind of recursive definition.

`delete(object(x))` deletes the object and also shows a deleted object when accessing `object(y).neighbour(p)`, but the number of neighbours still is the same. The list of neighbors now is just a number of existing objects and one deleted object. This hinders me when accessing properties in a way like this: `[object(y).neighbour.size]`, because for the deleted neighbour the property cannot be accessed.

Right now I always loop over all neighbours of an object I want to delete, find out which of their neighbours is the object I want to delete, and delete the links:

```
objects(y).neighbour(p)=[]
objects(a).neighbour(b)=[]
objects(d).neighbour(f)=[]
% etc...
object(x)=[]
```

There must be a more efficient way to do this? Do I have to change the way the objects are linked together to achieve what I want?

Comment: Because you use a handle class, every reference to an object is the object itself, but all references refer to the same, unique object, no copies are made. This is as close to a pointer as you can come. In a language that uses pointers, you'd have exactly the same issue as you have here, and you'd have to visit neighbors to delete pointers to the object being deleted. You can write a `delete` method in your class that does this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-class-destructors.html

Comment: As an alternative, use a non-handle class. You can define an array of objects of your class, and the `neighbors` property is a list of indices into the array. It depends on what exactly you're doing if that is efficient or not. Typically it's easier to work with non-handle classes, because they behave like any other normal MATLAB data.